# Pushing GCP Pub/Sub Message with JSON array to separate rows in BigQuery using BigQuery Subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using Big query subscription to push message from GCP Pub/Sub to BigQuery.
Now, just to save on cost, I am pushing more different messages in a single message. Is there any way to break those message and push those in different rows in big query.

Message looks like this :

```
[{"name":"1","gender":"F"},{"name":"2","gender":"F"},{"name":"3","gender":"F"}]
```

I want to push all 3 json in different rows, is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: No, you have to query the sink table to extract/reformat your data as expected. It's often the case, the raw data from PubSub are rarely directly useful, they required a post processing, at least a view.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it **on write** as pointed out in the comment.

However, you can do it **on read** using [`JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array) as follows:

```sql
WITH
  input AS (
  SELECT
    '[{"name":"1","gender":"F"},{"name":"2","gender":"F"},{"name":"3","gender":"F"}]' AS json
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '[{"name":"1","gender":"F"},{"name":"2","gender":"F"},{"name":"3","gender":"F"}]' )
SELECT
  record
FROM
  input,
  UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json)) record;
```

which produces:

| Row | record |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `"name":"1","gender":"F"}` |
| 2 | `{"name":"2","gender":"F"}` |
| 3 | `{"name":"3","gender":"F"}` |
| 4 | `{"name":"1","gender":"F"}` |
| 5 | `{"name":"2","gender":"F"}` |
| 6 | `{"name":"3","gender":"F"}` |

You can then deserialize it further by transforming JSON fields into table columns using [`JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_scalar):

```sql
WITH input AS (
  SELECT '[{"name":"1","gender":"F"},{"name":"2","gender":"F"},{"name":"3","gender":"F"}]' as json UNION ALL
  SELECT '[{"name":"1","gender":"F"},{"name":"2","gender":"F"},{"name":"3","gender":"F"}]'
)
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(record, "$.name") name,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(record, "$.gender") gender
FROM input, UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json)) record;
```

which produces:

| Row | name | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | F |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |

More on the BigQuery JSON operators [in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions).